# How to say that a shirt is similar to a linen shirt? Does linen-like or linen-look work?

Tags: word-choice, hyphens

I want to say that someone wears shirts similar to linen shirts.

Would "He was always wearing a linen-like shirt/linen-look shirt" be correct? Which option is more common, if they are correct? Is the hyphen mandatory?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=linenlike%2Clinen-like%2Clinen-look&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 It looks like the hyphenated form "linen-like" is significantly *more common* than "linenlike", but both exist. "linen-look" is the least frequently occurring (and also the only one that doesn't sound right to me). It seems like **"linen-like"** would be your best choice!

Comment: Linen Look seems to be a trade name for a type of polyester fabric.  It's not clear to me how a shirt can be "like a linen shirt" unless it is a linen shirt. I'd favour spelling it out  "He  wears shirts that are like linen shirts."  rather than form a hyphenated form.

Comment: @JamesK, my sentences target a public that is more familiar with different kinds of fabric. I could also say "loose dress shirt", but saying that it is linen-like also brings the texture and other aspects of linen that I also want to imply.

Comment: Thank you, @QuackE.Duck. I'm glad to accept your comment as an answer if you answer it. I didn't know this Google feature.

Comment: @sidney I only found out about it from using this site :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for all three terms in the Google Books Ngrams Viewer produced these results:
[image]

which shows that **linen-like** is the most common term by a significant margin.

As @JamesK has commented, you may not want to use "linen-look" as a *generic* term, since it seems to be a brand name. It's also the least commonly used term of the three.